# Calling the asynchronous chrome.tabs.create inside a for loop

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, for-loop, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

So I am trying to create a bunch of tabs from a list of tabs in a list names groups like this..

```
console.log("groups.length: " + groups.length);
// loop through groups
    for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
        // create the new tab
        console.log("for loop ran: " + i);

        // cannot use i in here because async
        chrome.tabs.create({
            windowId: win.id,
            index: i,
            url: groups[i].urls[0]
        }, function(tab){
            console.log("i: " + i);
            groups[i].tabId = tab.id;  // this is not working right!!!
        });
    }
```

So in the terminal I get..

```
groups.length: 2
popup.js:87 for loop ran: 0
popup.js:87 for loop ran: 1
popup.js:95 i: 2
popup.js:95 i: 2
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on here. I thought that even though the task is async it should still input the value of i as it was when the call was first made. Also why would line 95 ever show i = 2? How could i ever be greater than 1? I'm really confused, thanks kind internet programmers.

Comment: The explanation part is documented in an excellent answer here: [Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23667087/3959875).

Answer (score 0):

```
groups.forEach(function (group, i) {
    chrome.tabs.create({
        windowId: win.id,
        index: i,
        url: group.urls[0]
    }, function(tab){
        group.tabId = tab.id;
    });
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. The groups in the groups array does not include the correct tab ID afterward.

Comment: Your code had scope issue, now you have an api issue. What if you log out every tab object?

Comment: They are all exactly what I want them to be.

Answer (score 0):

After your code ran, `i` is 2 because in a `for` loop, the increment expression `i++` is executed after each loop cycle, and then the condition is checked to determine. So the code executes as follows:
`first_cycle -> increment (i is 1 now) -> check_condition (true) -> second_cycle -> increment (i is 2 now) -> check_condition (false) -> abort loop`

Change your callback function to:

```
function(tab) {
    console.log("index" + tab.index);
    groups[tab.index].tabId = tab.id;
}
```

because this way, code within the callback function does not use the variable `i` of the outer function (more about lexical scope and closures [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

... or use artit91's solution.